# Python Script - Permission Denied - Linux

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to execute my Python script using just the script's filename, i.e., `test-script.py`, however, I get a permission denied error.

The script is executable (x bit set) and I have the `#!/usr/bin/env python3` at the top of the script. Also, my script directory is in the PATH variable (so I don't need to type `./test-script.py` from the script directory).

It works when I type in: `python3 test-script.py`, but just gives a permission denied error with `test-script.py`.

FYI, I'm a normal user. I'm not part of the sudo group.

Is there a way to fix this?

```
faheem@jumpbox ~ $ ls -l python-scripts/test-script.py
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 faheem users 1729 May 11 15:03 python-scripts/test-script.py
faheem@jumpbox ~ $ test-script.py
-bash: /home/faheem/python-scripts/test-script.py: Permission denied
```

Thanks.